# Getting website displayed correctly in Google

Tags: html, wordpress, search, meta-tags

I have a website that is now listed in Google's search directory, but it will only display 'Home' as title and will not display a descriptive text as it would for other results found. This is the search I've done to retrieve my website: [here](http://www.google.ca/#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=physics+crossfit+orleans&pbx=1&oq=physics+crossfit+orleans&aq=f&aqi=g1&aql=1&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=6209l6720l1l7019l7l6l0l0l0l0l203l717l1.3.1l6l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=eb4a289355d571b0&biw=1920&bih=588). It's the 8th result (for me, might be different for you guys), but it's the only one that has no description attached to itself and no title (only Home).

I assume the title has got to do with the  tags in my html, though if you have a look at the website's source code, the title is not Home. So I'm not quite sure what to do here. Also, I'm using wordpress for this website so maybe there's something I should be doing on the server-side to fix this?

I always assumed google would extract directly from the page, so I have no idea what to do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing the page title used to be 'home' and Google just hasn't caught up with the change yet. Google doesn't check every time it returns your page as a result (think about how that would work).

You could also update the meta description tag in your homepage so Google can present a proper description of your site to searchers.

Comment: Additionally in your HTML head you have the meta tag `<meta name='robots' content='noindex,nofollow' />`. Why do you try to prevent from getting indexed? If I understand you right you want to be indexed. Maybe google has a old version of your page in it`s index, but isn't allowed to update because of your metatag.

Comment: Thanks FlyBy for catching this. It's not set directly in the html markup so maybe it's being set by wordpress? Again, my knowledge is very limited when it comes to anything web past html/css markup so this is all new to me. I'll fix this, thanks :)